# joomla html 5 ie7 template

Tags: html, templates, joomla, internet-explorer-7

i am making an  html5 template for joomla.
every thing works in chrome,safari,ff and ie8,ie9

ie7 render very wrong.
it renders the html 5 elements due to a script but renders it wrong.

please help me, what am i doing wrong?

thanks.

site is: dev.talamasterclass.com

links for the source code and template: 
[www.3dyonic.com/zip/html5template.zip](http://www.3dyonic.com/zip/html5template.zip)

any help will be appriciated. 
template has html overrides but they are not relevant, index.php and css/template.css and mabye th js folder are the files rellevant i think.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your head.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
   <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE7.js"></script>
   <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: no worries. if this is what you were looking for, please accept the answer. thanks